# Xamarin Forms ListView Data Binding

Tags: xaml, listview, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

`ObservableCollection<string> CompanyList` in the xaml.cs code behind is tied to `<ListView>` element in the xaml. Left alone, it displays a list of the strings in `CompanyList` as expected.

However, I want to customize (purely for style purposes) the `ViewCell` in the `ListView` while leaving `CompanyList` as a collection of `string`s. I am unsure how to bind the `string` company list value.

```
    <ListView x:Name="CompanyList" ItemTapped="OnAddCompanyFilterTapped" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0">
              <StackLayout  Padding="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding ??????????}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
              </StackLayout>                  
              <BoxView Style="{StaticResource divider}"/>
            </StackLayout>                
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

What do I put in the ??????? to get the string in `CompanyList` to show?

Any help/suggestions/ideas is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding Path=.` should do it, which can be shortened:

```
<Label Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
```

Assumes the `ListView.ItemsSource` remains `CompanyList`.

Comment: THANKS! lol was stuck on this for a bit cause I didn't have a property to bind it ><". I'll accept when Stack allows me (time requirement). Thanks again!